# Generating child elements based upon a previously generated parent object

Tags: javascript

So, new to JavaScript. Currently, I have two separate classes of objects, as represented below by "Parents" and "Children." These parents are printed to the page with the function BuildObjects. This works fine. However, I'd also like to have the Children objects be printed into the Parent object, based upon each object's category.

Example code:

```
Parents=[];
Children=[];
Parent=function(name,desc)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.desc=desc;
    Parents[this.name]=this;
}

new Parent('Example 1','Example desc 1');
new Parent('Example 2','Example desc 2');
new Parent('Example 3','Example desc 3');

Child=function(name,desc,parentname)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.desc=desc;
    this.parentname=parentname;
    Children[this.name]=this;
}

new Child('Example 1 Child 1','Example desc 1','Example 1');
new Child('Example 1 Child 2','Example desc 2','Example 1');
new Child('Example 1 Child 1','Example desc 3','Example 2');
new Child('Example 2 Child 2','Example desc 4','Example 2');

function BuildObjects() {
    var out = '';
    for (var i in Parents) {
        out += '<p id="' + Parents[i].category + '">' + Parents[i].name + '</p><p>' + Parents[i].desc + '</p><p>';
    }
    document.getElementById("textcontainer").innerHTML = out;
}
```

How would I go about doing this? What would be the most easily extensible way of implementing this? I've thought of creating a child object within the parent object, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that, or if that's even possible. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget to `var` your variable names somewhere.

Comment: In fact, why don't you create these nodes directly in a _#document-fragment_ instead of as some intermediate objects in _Arrays_?

Comment: Perhaps I should have included a bit more detail in the original post, but the idea is that each of these objects will be assigned an onclick function and used for a store-type structure. By creating the objects with JavaScript, it's a lot easier to manage adding new entries, so I was hoping to use that.

Comment: Based on category or name.. what if there are 2 parents with the same category cat1 and 5 children with the same category

Comment: Ideally no two parents would share a category. So it'd probably be better for the Children to just be attached to the Parent's name. Will edit the question to reflect.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v616hjhh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of access you can maintain another meta object which will group the children based on its category, then use it to print the children

```
Parents = {};
Children = {};
ChildrenCatMap = {};
Parent = function (name, desc, category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.category = category;
    Parents[this.name] = this;
}

new Parent('Example 1', 'Example desc 1', 'category1');
new Parent('Example 2', 'Example desc 2', 'category2');
new Parent('Example 3', 'Example desc 3', 'category3');

Child = function (name, desc, category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.category = category;
    Children[this.name] = this;
    if (!ChildrenCatMap[category]) {
        ChildrenCatMap[category] = [];
    }
    ChildrenCatMap[category].push(this);
}

new Child('Example 1', 'Example desc 1', 'category1');
new Child('Example 2', 'Example desc 2', 'category1');
new Child('Example 3', 'Example desc 3', 'category2');
new Child('Example 4', 'Example desc 4', 'category2');

function BuildObjects() {
    var out = '',
        children;
    for (var i in Parents) {
        out += '<p id="' + Parents[i].category + '">' + Parents[i].name + '</p><p>' + Parents[i].desc + '</p>';
        children = ChildrenCatMap[Parents[i].category];
        if (children) {
            out += '<ul>';
            for (var j in children) {
                out += '<li id="' + children[j].category + '">' + children[j].name + '</p><p>' + children[j].desc + '</li>';
            }
            out += '</ul>';
        }
        out += '<p>';
    }
    document.getElementById("textcontainer").innerHTML = out;
}
BuildObjects();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v616hjhh/)